# Regex remove hyperlinks for a specific domain

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex

How do I extract the text from link HTML element if the URL matches a particular domain?

E.g. extract `hello` from:

```
<a href="https://example.com/2018/11/22/ff/">hello</a>
```

If the URL wasn't `example.com`, then it should ignore it.

I'm using regex `</?a(|\s+[^>]+)>` but it works for all domains when it should only work for `example.com`.

Comment: [Don't use r̩̟̳̺͙͜e̩̮̲͓͕g̳̩͎̳ḙ̙x̀ to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1064767), use [DomDocument](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). Also don't use regex to parse URLs, use [`parse_url()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: am using a pluginon wordpress that do regex so am tight with regex :)

Comment: Use `/<a\shref=\"https?:\/\/example.com[^"]+\">([^<]+)<\/a>/` https://regex101.com/r/VAUDQW/1/

Answer (score 0):

I am a noob developer! But i think this will work for you!

```
//The website you want to block
var regex = /example.com/g
// Select all anchor text from the window
var textLink = document.querySelectorAll("a");

//Check all anchor from the windows if they contain the "example.com" if they do, the href will be replace with "#"
textLink.forEach(  e => {
    if(regex.test(e.href)){
    e.href = "#";
}});
```